# Dropdown not working in mozilla firefox but working for chrome

Tags: html, css

I was trying to create a dropdown.

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown_container">
   <select class="my_dropdown" id="my_dropdown">
      <option value="1">LONG OPTION</option>
      <option value="2">short</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.dropdown_container {
  width:300px;
  color: rgb(9, 9, 12);
}

select.my_dropdown {
  width: 250px;
  height: 20px;
}

option{
 width: 200px;
 height: 60px;
}
```

Chrome Result
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHjfj.png

Firefox Result
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfYmg.png

Comment: I think there might be more to your problem - remarkably, something unusual is happening with your dropdown font even in Chrome, and this does work fine when testing with the given HTML+CSS alone in Firefox 85

Answer (score 1):

I can't confirm your issue. It`s working fine in Firefox. See the snippet:

```css
div.dropdown_container {
  width:300px;
  color: rgb(9, 9, 12);
}

select.my_dropdown {
  width: 250px;
  height: 20px;
}

option{
 width: 200px;
 height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown_container">
   <select class="my_dropdown" id="my_dropdown">
      <option value="1">LONG OPTION</option>
      <option value="2">short</option>
   </select>
</div>
```